# HP Pavilion with Radeon 6470M hangs with Black Screen on Boot

Tags: graphics, ati

I have recently purchased an HP Pavilion with a Radeon 6470M graphics card. I subsequently found out that this card is not yet supported for Ubuntu by ATI.

I followed the instructions of Post #2 in this thread ([ubuntuforums.org: No Compiz and No Unity in Ubuntu 11.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1760264)) and installed the xorg-edgers ppa, which I think helped. I have not installed the ATI drivers, as every time I tried them the graphics were abysmal. I will wait for the version where my card is supported.

However, there are times where when I boot that it hangs in a black screen. I have noticed that if it hangs, then the only way to get going is to boot with "nomodeset", and then restart, which seems to load the full graphics, using the generic drivers. This might simply be a coincidence (I haven't tried it enough times).

Is there anything I can do to stop this "hanging"

Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE: I have noticed that most times it hangs on the black screen and a few times it loads all the way. I'm assuming something conflicts, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: You're using a experimental PPA, it should come as no surprise that something goes wrong.

Comment: X-swat PPA is the one with the most recent and stable drivers.

Comment: Thank you, but whenever I try xswat, it says it can't locate it.

Comment: Are you sureyou added it corectly?

Comment: I did what was in this link (http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/ubuntu-x-swat?dist=natty) just the last line was "upgrade". I could have done it wrong though...

Answer (score 1):

I had given up trying and decided to wait for the 11.10 upgrade.

After upgrading to 11.10 I installed the ATI drivers and everything seems to be working. I'm assuming that it was an issue with Unity that has subsequently been fixed.