# Cannot detect ATI radeon HD6720G2

Tags: 11.10, installation, ati, radeon, hybrid

I wish to install ubuntu 11.10 on my new laptop but because the system cannot detect the graphic, then the screen are blank. How and what should i do ? I really want to use ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Hello, if you're still around, did either of the answers work?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the Radeon HD 6xxx series.

Take a look at the post and reply [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70998/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-11-10-64bit). It might help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

press F6 when grub menu appear. Select nomodeset. Esc.

It will  temporarily stop KMS support which try to detect appropriate driver for your graphics card. Now ubuntu will open in VGA mode. To fix the issue permanently : Edit /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

replace the line with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="radeon.modeset=1"
```

If it failed to fix the problem then edit the line too. **but check first before apply this step**.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```